# Use FactoryBot create_list and recreate object in every instance

Tags: rspec, factory-bot

This is a `before` part in `rspec`:

I want to create a new `object_b` every time `object_a` is created. Since FactoryBot works with lazy objects, `object_b` isn't recreated:

```
before do
  create_list(:object_a, 3, object_b: create(:object_b))
end
```

How do I tell FactoryBot to create a new `object_b` for every `object_a` in this `create_list`?

UPDATE: the weird thing is that

```
before do
  3.times { create(:object_a, object_b: create(:object_b)) }
end
```

does actually work

Comment: your second example is fine, create_list won't randomize any values unless you do a loop of some kind.

Comment: It is Rubocop with `rubocop -a`, however, that's converts `3.times` into a `create_list`. I've turned of the cop for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, `create(:object_b)` is being executed before `create_list` is in order to have a value to send in to the method. It is equivalent to

```rb
before do
  object_b = create(:object_b)
  create_list(:object_a, 3, object_b: object_b)
end
```

According to [this post by Hernan Velasquez](https://dev.to/hernamvel/the-optimal-way-to-create-a-set-of-records-with-factorybot-createlist-factorybot-buildlist-1j64) you should be able to create a new `object_b` for each `object_a` without using `.times` by using `build_list`, and assigning `object_b` and saving inside a block sent to that method.

```rb
before do
  build_list(:object_a, 3) do |object_a, i|
    object_a.object_b = object_b
    object_a.save!
  end
end
```